How do I get back to a branch checkout if Pycharm says I need to move or remove untracked working tree files?
Somehow I wound up with a "master" branch in my project in addition to the "main" branch I thought I had been working and committing. I didn't create the "master" branch but it may have been something I enabled or disabled in PyCharm. No idea.
I wanted to consolidate them, but got GitHub errors that it wouldn't merge unrelated histories and it wouldn't merge to the protected "main" branch. I have not set GitHub protections on the main branch, so I'm not sure where else it might be getting protected. Now, I'm stuck with PyCharm in the local main branch and it won't let me switch back to my local master or remote "master" which I have renamed "secondary" via GitHub browser.
Untracked files are project files
I went straight to the git documentation looking for the correct answer to give it when it said "are you sure you want to merge main and secondary?" and "yes" or "y" was not the right keyword. I used --continue and then the trouble started.
Trying git checkout master or git checkout secondary now gives me an error message that there are untracked files and keeps aborting the operation. Could anyone help me out of this mess, or am I better off closing my local project, deleting its whole folder structure, and then using the PyCharm wizard to open a clone of my online repo fresh?
16:36:00.377: [AdventofCode2024] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false checkout -b secondary origin/secondary --
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    .idea/inspectionProfiles/profiles_settings.xml
    .idea/misc.xml
    .idea/vcs.xml
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting

I referenced older questions too.
How to move files from one git branch to another
What is protected git branch?
**Unable to switch branches in git, shows error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout
**
The third one is my problem. This same question has been asked a few more times but all the Q&As are more than five years old; plus, I don't know how to untrack my .idea and .venv files if the .gitignore is INSIDE the .venv files.

It depends on what you want to do with those files, save them? Discard them? Ignore them?
Since it's .idea I assume you would want to ignore them, try adding .idea/* to your .gitignore.
